# Call winform function from IE browser

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I have a winform that screen scrapes another application and generates a html file. I'd like to add js to the html file so that when a user clicks a heading, it will send a string and trigger a function within the winform.

I've been researching this for a while now but all of the possible solutions I've seen involve the webbrowser control, which I'm not using and don't intend to use.

Is it possible to call a winform function from an IE page via js?

UPDATE: Now considering a webbrowser control.

Comment: My first reaction would be: thank God (or w3c consortium), no. But it's not clear to me where/how you host this "IE page" (or what you mean exactly by an "IE page"). Maybe you should edit your question and show some relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `WebBrowser` control you can set the object for scripting property to a class with public methods that you want to expose to javascript:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)] //required
class MyJsInterface
{
  public string Test()
  {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}

browser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyJsInterface(); //for example
```

Then, you can call the methods in `MyJsInterface` from javascript using `window.external` object:

```
//add this script to document.onload or in a script tag at the end of the document

//var headings = document.getElementsByClassName("heading");
//var headings = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++)
{
   var element = headings[i];
 //element.addEventListener("click", function () {
   element.attachEvent("click", function () {
     var text = window.external.Test();
     alert(text);
   }
}
```

In Internet Explorer versions prior to IE 9, you have to use `attachEvent` rather than the standard `addEventListener`:
[Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

It's also possible to invoke javascript methods from code behind.
Read more here:
[Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx)

Comment: Ended up slightly modifying on my end to use jQuery and classes: `$(".class").click(function () {
    var text = window.external.testFunction();
    alert(text);
});`

Comment: Of course, it's up to you how you attach event listeners and on which elements. I'm glad to hear that this solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Override `WndProc` (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771034/c-sharp-override-wndproc-in-control-level-to-detect) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx)) on your form and listen for [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx) messages. Translate the points based on the location of the Web Browser control. Then use [IHtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752641(v=vs.85).aspx) ([mshtml object library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(v=vs.85).aspx)) to access the DOM and find the element at that position (using [elementFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417(v=vs.85).aspx)).